# How to 'Trim' a multi line string?

Tags: c#, string, text, trim

I am trying to use `Trim()` on a multi line string, however only the first line will `Trim()`. I can't seem to figure out how to remove all white space from the beginning of each line.

```
string temp1 = "   test   ";
string temp2 = @"   test
                    line 2 ";

MessageBox.Show(temp1.Trim());
//shows "test".

MessageBox.Show(temp2.Trim());
//shows "test"
        "       line2 ".
```

Can I use `Trim`/`TrimStart`/`TrimEnd` on a multi line string?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Can I use Trim/TrimStart/TrimEnd on a multi line string?

Yes, but it only Trims the string *as a whole*, and does not pay attention to each line within the string's content.

If you need to Trim each line, you could do something like:

```
string trimmedByLine = string.Join(
                             "\n", 
                             temp2.Split('\n').Select(s => s.Trim()));
```

Answer (score 13):

This trims each line

```
temp2 = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    temp2.Split(new []{Environment.NewLine},StringSplitOptions.None)
         .Select(l => l.Trim()));
```

Comment: Ended up using your code, just gave the best answer to the other user because he included why Trim doesn't work. Thank you though.

Answer (score 2):

Working solution using regular expressions:

```csharp
string TrimMultiline(string text)
{
    return new Regex(@"^[^\S\n]+(.+?)\s*$", RegexOptions.Multiline).Replace(text, "$1");
}
```

Or if you want TrimStart (this is the same RegEx as Martin Smith's comment):

```csharp
string TrimStartMultiline(string text)
{
    return new Regex(@"^[^\S\n]+(.+)$", RegexOptions.Multiline).Replace(text, "$1");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string temp3 = String.Join(
                    Environment.NewLine, 
                    temp2.Split(new char[] { '\n', '\r' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                         .Select(s => s.Trim()));
```

Comment: Removing empty entries may not be appropriate here.  That will remove extra line feeds...

Comment: @ReedCopsey but also it maybe what OP wants. who knows

Comment: Removing extra line feeds means that all-empty lines inside in the middle of the string will be completely removed. I'd make the bold claim that this is unlikely what _anyone_ wants... :)

Answer (score 0):

split, trim, join

```
string[] lines = temp1.Split(new []{Environment.NewLine});
lines = lines.Select(l=>l.Trim()).ToArray();
string temp2 = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions to do this.

Here's a PHP (I'm on a Mac, so no C#) preg_replace example that does this

```
<?php

$test = "   line 1     
     line 2 with blanks at end     
     line 3 with tabs at end        ";

print $test;

$regex = '/[ \t]*\n[ \t]*/';
$res = trim(preg_replace($regex, "\n", $test));
print $res;
```

The regex preg_replace removes the blanks around line feeds, the trim removes those at the beginning and end.

The C# Regex.Replace method should work like the preg_replace.

Comment: Could you elaborate? What regular expression would you use? Give some sample code.

Comment: I've added an example in PHP, as I explained the C# Regex.Replace method should be similar to the PHP preg_replace function.

Comment: In C# `temp2 = new Regex(@"^[^\S\n]+(.+)$", RegexOptions.Multiline).Replace(temp2 , "$1");` would do the job.

Answer (score -1):

Off topic, but in PowerShell watch-out when you use this code:

```
$content = Get-Content file.txt;
$trimmed = $content.Trim();
```

Since, not obviously, `$content` is an *array* of lines so PS will magically perform a `Trim` for each line.

Forcing it into a string:

```
[System.String]$content = Get-Content file.txt;
```

Won't work since PowerShell then removes all carriage returns to make a single line..!